# textview overflowing out of the screen

Tags: android

i have this problem where i create a x number of textview in my layout to store 1 character in each text view.

however when the text gets too long, the text would not go to the next line and it will get overflowed out of the screen

is there anyway for me to keep the textviews in 1 screen?

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        TextView[] tv = new TextView[counter];
        float textSize = 65;

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
                tv[i] = new TextView(this);
                tv[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
                tv[i].setTextSize(textSize);
                tv[i].setText(""+singleText[i]);
                linearLayout.addView(tv[i]); 
        }
        setContentView(linearLayout);
```

[image]

Comment: Aren't you using the android:inputType="textMultiLine"?

Comment: so sorry i forgotten to add my code in.. have update the question

Comment: try this ...... 
linearLayout.addView(tv[i],LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: erm still doesn't work it instead becomes each character has a fill parent width

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using this [TextView.setSingleLine(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSingleLine%28boolean%29)

Then you will not have the issue of text overflow.

Comment: hmmm the set single line doesn't work because each of the letters are in a different textview... i have assigned 1 text view for each character